# ngnix бесконечный цикл

Tags: php, nginx, config

Пробую записать редирект для ngnix чтобы все запросы кроме медиа проходили через index.php файл

```
    server{
listen 80;
root /var/www/projects/project;
index index.php;
server_name URL;

 location /index.php {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }

 location ^(.*)$ {
  try_files ^ /index.php?$1;
 }

 location ~ ^/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|woff))$ {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
   return 404;
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              rev Line     M-▲ Scroll Up
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ext Line     M-▼ Scroll Down        

 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
```

После выполнения запроса меня рекурсивно перекидывает на index.php с чем я ничего не могу поделать. Пробую переделать конфиг с апачи, который выглядел так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/css/(.*).css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/images/(.*).png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/images/(.*).jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/lib/jquery/(.*).js

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap/app.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Так же я попробовал использовать конфиг ларавеля, но что-то пошло не так. Те же самые кольцевые редиректы:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name имя;
    root /var/www/projects/проект/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
```

Comment: `return /$;` это зачем?

Comment: пробовал вывести что-нибудь, исправил на рабочую но с редиректом